# Access cell based on sheet name in another cell

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a bunch of sheets, named uninterestingly `Main` and then `ModelA`, `ModelB`, ... In `Main`, I just want to aggregate the models on these various sheets.

How can I structure it so that if cell `A1` contains the name of a sheet (e.g. `ModelA`) then cell `B1` contains the value of `C14` in the cell in the sheet referenced by `A1`. (Explicitly, this would be `='ModelA'!C14`, but I don't want to be explicit).

Comment: I think you're looking for the INDIRECT constructor.

Comment: @Lance Yes, looks like I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will have the Sheet name in column A and want to see whatever sheet that is, but cell C14's value?

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C14")
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think this is what you want based on your question:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!" & B1)
```

Comment: I wanted the C14 to be within the quotes, Glib has it right.